# Подключение библиотек из произвольного места

Tags: qt, winapi

Как сделать так , что бы собранный `.exe` файл проекта тянул стандартные библиотеки не рядом с собой , а допустим из директории выше . Например `Qt5Core.dll` находилась в директории `C:\Users\admin\Documents\ModRelease\release`,а должна находится в директории `C:\Users\admin\Documents\ModRelease\resource`.Что нужно дописать в `.pro`? или как нужно исправить `#include` тянущихся классов.

Comment: ::SetDllDirectory (path)

Comment: `void QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths ( const QStringList & paths )`

Answer (score 1):

Если используется явная линковка, то можно указать путь для поиска библиотек с помощью [::SetDllDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya), будет влиять на все последующие LoadLibrary (LoadLibraryEx).

Если используется неявная линковка, то можно воспользоваться отложенной загрузкой библиотек, передав [/DELAYLOAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=vs-2019) линкеру, например `/DELAYLOAD:libcef.dll`.
Далее в коде до первого использования библиотек указываем, где искать `::SetDllDirectoryA(dir)` и загружаем отложенные библиотеки `::__HrLoadAllImportsForDll("libcef.dll")`